# Creating User using sample code in wso2 Identity server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

List Users Code :

```
package Charon;

import org.apache.wink.client.ClientConfig;
import org.apache.wink.client.ClientWebException;
import org.apache.wink.client.Resource;
import org.apache.wink.client.RestClient;
import org.apache.wink.client.handlers.ClientHandler;
import org.wso2.charon.core.client.SCIMClient;
import org.wso2.charon.core.schema.SCIMConstants;
import org.wso2.charon.samples.utils.CharonResponseHandler;
import org.wso2.charon.utils.authentication.BasicAuthHandler;
import org.wso2.charon.utils.authentication.BasicAuthInfo;



public class GetUser {


    public static final String Username = "admin";
    public static final String Password = "admin";
    public static final String URL =    "https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            //create SCIM client
            SCIMClient scimClient = new SCIMClient();
            //create a apache wink ClientHandler to intercept and identify response messages
            CharonResponseHandler responseHandler = new CharonResponseHandler();
            responseHandler.setSCIMClient(scimClient);
            //set the handler in wink client config
            ClientConfig clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
            clientConfig.handlers(new ClientHandler[]{responseHandler});
            //create a wink rest client with the above config
            RestClient restClient = new RestClient(clientConfig);

            BasicAuthInfo basicAuthInfo = new BasicAuthInfo();
            basicAuthInfo.setUserName(Username);
            basicAuthInfo.setPassword(Password);

            BasicAuthHandler basicAuthHandler = new BasicAuthHandler();
            BasicAuthInfo encodedBasicAuthInfo = (BasicAuthInfo) basicAuthHandler.getAuthenticationToken(basicAuthInfo);

            //create resource endpoint to access a known user resource.
            Resource userResource = restClient.resource(URL);
            String response = userResource.
                header(SCIMConstants.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, encodedBasicAuthInfo.getAuthorizationHeader()).
                contentType(SCIMConstants.APPLICATION_JSON).accept(SCIMConstants.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .get(String.class);

            //decode the response
            System.out.println(response);
        } catch (ClientWebException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getRequest().getEntity());
            System.out.println(e.getResponse().getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The Following is the response i get :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.wink.client.ClientRuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.apache.wink.client.internal.ResourceImpl.invoke(ResourceImpl.java:240)
    at org.apache.wink.client.internal.ResourceImpl.invoke(ResourceImpl.java:189)
    at org.apache.wink.client.internal.ResourceImpl.get(ResourceImpl.java:302)
    at Charon.GetUser.main(GetUser.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at org.apache.wink.client.internal.handlers.HttpURLConnectionHandler.handle(HttpURLConnectionHandler.java:57)
    at org.apache.wink.client.internal.handlers.HandlerContextImpl.doChain(HandlerContextImpl.java:52)
    at org.apache.wink.client.internal.handlers.AcceptHeaderHandler.handle(AcceptHeaderHandler.java:79)
    at org.apache.wink.client.internal.handlers.HandlerContextImpl.doChain(HandlerContextImpl.java:52)
    at org.wso2.charon.samples.utils.CharonResponseHandler.handle(CharonResponseHandler.java:44)
    at org.apache.wink.client.internal.handlers.HandlerContextImpl.doChain(HandlerContextImpl.java:52)
    at org.apache.wink.client.internal.ResourceImpl.invoke(ResourceImpl.java:227)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.wink.client.internal.handlers.HttpURLConnectionHandler.processRequest(HttpURLConnectionHandler.java:97)
    at org.apache.wink.client.internal.handlers.HttpURLConnectionHandler.handle(HttpURLConnectionHandler.java:54)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 28 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are accessing through https, you must have your own keystore and WSO2 Identity Server's public certificate should be added to your keystore/truststore.

You can use WSO2 keysstore as your own keystore, so that, you don't need to have your own keystore.

```
// set these properties, this is used for authentication over https to the registry
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "wso2is-5.1.0/repository/resources/securitywso2carbon.jks"); //provide full path here
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "wso2carbon");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType","JKS");
```